# Throwing exception if lambda expression fails

Tags: c#, exception, lambda

To simplify, let's say I have a method that should return a `User` object from an ID found in a list of users. If no user is found I want to throw an `Exception`.

My current code works:

```
public User GetUserFromID(int id)
{
    foreach (User u in Users)
        if (u.id == id)
            return u;
    
    throw new Exception("No user is found");
}
```

But my problem comes when I want to find a user with a lambda expression instead of the `foreach` loop. The following code succeeds in returning the correct `User` object but never throws an exception if nothing is found.

```
public User GetUserFromID(int id)
{
    return Users.Find(u => u.id == id);
    
    throw new Exception("No user is found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `User.Single(...)` which would throw an exception if there isn't exactly one match:

```
public User GetUserFromID(int id)
{
    return Users.Single(u => u.id == id);
}
```

---

Just for completeness, if you wanted to throw your own exception, then you could do something like this.

Using `SingleOrDefault` will return `null` if there is no match or if there is more than 1 match, so you can check for `null` to determine if an exception should be thrown:

```
public User GetUserFromID(int id)
{
    var user = Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.id == id);

    if(user == null)
        throw new Exception("No user is found");
 
    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public User GetUserFromID(int id)
{
    return Users.Single(u => u.id == id);
}
```

`Users.Single` will throw an exception when there is not exactly one match.